# Crystal Reports XI PrintToPrinter "Missing parameter values"

Tags: printing, parameters, crystal-reports, reporting

I'm working on an issue with a Crystal report (Crystal XI running in a VB app) where a sporadic "Missing parameter values" error is received when trying to print the report directly. Here's a summary of the issue:

1. User runs the report via the report menu (everything works fine)
2. User clicks 'Print Preview' (everything works fine)
3. User clicks 'Print' (supposed to send the document directly to the printer, but sometimes get missing parameter error)

Here is what I had for code to start:

```
    crystalReportViewer.MdiParent = parent
    crystalReportViewer.Show()

    Dim report As ReportDocument = CType(crystalReportViewer.ReportSource, ReportDocument)

    report.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)
    crystalReportViewer.Close()
    crystalReportViewer.Dispose()
```

Based on what I've been googling, I came up with this code:

```
    crystalReportViewer.MdiParent = parent
    crystalReportViewer.Show()

    Dim report As ReportDocument = CType(crystalReportViewer.ReportSource, ReportDocument)

    'here are my attempts to get it to work
    Dim pf As ParameterFields = report.ParameterFields
    report.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"

    report.PrintToPrinter(1, False, 0, 0)
    crystalReportViewer.Close()
    crystalReportViewer.Dispose()
```

I'm about out of ideas on how to solve this issue. Has anyone else run across this?

Comment: can you share the exception you are getting..?

Comment: Here's a screenshot of the error: http://tinypic.com/r/6tl84z/6

Answer (score 2):

**Start Code:** You problably have some empty parameter in your report.

**After Search Code:** You have this line:

```
Dim pf As ParameterFields = report.ParameterFields
```

You have a parameter, and you are not setting any value.

**For both, use:**

```
//[C#]
report.setParameterValue(parameterName, parameterValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple. Make sure that all of your parameters inside the report are filled and thrown data before using "printtoprinter". I have solved it with that.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, this looks like an issue in Crystal. I couldn't find a fix, so I'm just using a workaround until a fix is available (report is generated and then printed manually).

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add **PrintDialog** from **toolBox**
then add the following code **button_click_event**

```
        ReportName.PrintOptions.PrinterName = PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName

        ReportName.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation = CrystalDecisions.[Shared].PaperOrientation.Landscape

        ReportName.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"

        ReportName.PrintToPrinter(PrintDialog1.PrinterSettings.Copies, True, 1, 99)
```

This would send printing directly to "Microsoft XPS Document Writer". vote if you found this helpful